# WPF Performance Suite throws BadImageFormatException

Tags: wpf

I need to profile my `WPF` 4.0 application. When I try to open it in `WPF Performance Suite 4.0` (from `Windows SDK 7.1`) it throws a `BadImageFormatException`:

[image]

It complains about a newer runtime, so I ran `corflags` on my `exe` to check the runtime version. It says:

```
Version   : v4.0.30319
CLR Header: 2.5
PE        : PE32
CorFlags  : 1
ILONLY    : 1
32BIT     : 0
Signed    : 0
```

What's wrong? Why can't I open this `WPF` application in the profiler?

### UPDATE

Tried JeffRSon's suggestion which produced another exception:

```
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at Microsoft.WpfPerformance.ToolAssembly..ctor(Assembly assembly)
   at Microsoft.WpfPerformance.Controls.AddToolDialog.ScanAssembly(String filename)
   at Microsoft.WpfPerformance.Controls.AddToolDialog.ScanAssembly()
```

Comment: Have you checked the WPF Performance Suite version? AFAICT, there were issues updating it when installing SDK7.1

Comment: It says 4.0. Hmm. Do I need to reboot my computer for this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a file called `WpfPerf_managed.exe.config` in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Windows Performance Toolkit\WPF Performance Suite` or wherever WPF Performance Suite is installed with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
   <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
   </startup>
</configuration>
```

This enables side-by-side runtimes in one process.

Restart WPF Performance Suite and load your assembly.

Comment: Interesting! However, I got another error instead. See my updated question.

Comment: Hard to say without details about "one or more of the requested types". Anything unusual in your assembly? Maybe try it first with some minimum implementation?

Comment: Hm. I'm using `MEF` for plugin handling. Could it be that the current directory is not set correctly when loading the exe?

Comment: Possible. But I don't have any useful idea, currently. Maybe try some sample app without MEF first.